# Run Swing jar on Linux

Tags: java, linux, swing, deployment, jar

I have compiled and created the jar file for my project made in Java Swing with JavaFX.
Now I want to run the project on Linux . For it I have to run my setup on Linux and it picks the directory path from the windows with `System.getProperty("user.dir");`
      I want the equivalent command in Linux.

How to run Java Swing jar on Linux?

Comment: *"How to run Java Swing jar on Linux?"*  Deploy it with [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  To ensure the user has a suitable minimum JRE, use [`deployJava.js`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html). JWS works to install/update Swing/JavaFX apps. on Linux (and Windows & OS X).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) is common for all operating systems.`System.getProperties("user.dir");` return your execution directory (where you run the main class) in execution.

**Answer for you comment :**

1. Keep your executable in user directory `/home/userName`.
2. If your `jar` has a main class and that can run without any parameters, just double on the jar to get swing UI
3. If you need to pass parameters thru command line, create an `sh` file like `run.sh` with
   `java -jar yourjarName.jar argument1 argument2 ...`
4. Open command prompt and run `sh run.sh`

Comment: Note that this is not necessarily the current working directory

Comment: i have installed the jre1.7 for linux . then i have extracted the jre in root directory in linux now where should i put the jar file and how it will be executed.

Comment: @user1868052 whenever you want, you just need to write -cp and -jar options correctly in your command